# package runs as child but fails as grandchild

Tags: ssis, azure-data-factory, sql-server-data-tools

I have three packages:
packageA, PackageB & packageC.
Protectionlevel on all packages = `EncryptSensitiveWithPassword`

A calls B and B calls C

If I run A then I get this failure when B tries to call C

```
0xC001405F at CheckTable: Failed to decrypt an encrypted XML node because the password was not specified or not correct. Package load will attempt to continue without the encrypted information.
```

However, if I run B then C runs like a charm. This (imo) voids the possibility that the password is incorrect.

When I call A that calls B that calls C C fails with the 'encrypted' error

I noticed this behaviour at any 'grandchild package'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to be caused by the protectionlevel. When setting the protectionlevel to `DontSaveSensitive` problems went away.